# UML средство для mac

Tags: uml, mac, linux

Посоветуйте какую-нибудь программу для рисования  UML-диаграмм (желательно кроссплатформенную - мак/линукс). Что-нибудь не навороченное, для новичка. А также мануал какой-нибудь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Visual Paradigm for UML](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/download/vpuml.jsp). Есть бесплатная версия с некоторыми ограничениями (справа ссылка "Get Community Edition"), но для обучения сгодится. Должна быть версия для мака.

Answer (score 1):

Именно для рисования? [dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/)